gpg-agent can't connect to the daemon /usr/lib/gnupg/scdaemon
How can I solve this error I found I my logs:
set 04 09:56:37 hostname gpg-agent[PID]: can't connect to the daemon /usr/lib/gnupg/scdaemon: IPC connect call failed
set 04 09:56:38 hostname gpg-agent[PID]: can't connect to the daemon /usr/lib/gnupg/scdaemon: IPC connect call failed
set 04 09:56:39 hostname gpg-agent[PID]: can't connect to the daemon /usr/lib/gnupg/scdaemon: IPC connect call failed
set 04 09:56:40 hostname gpg-agent[PID]: can't connect to the daemon /usr/lib/gnupg/scdaemon: IPC connect call failed

Ubuntu version:
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 24.04.1 LTS
Release:        24.04
Codename:       noble


I checked the referenced file and it's missing:
$ ls -al /usr/lib/gnupg/scdaemon
ls: cannot access '/usr/lib/gnupg/scdaemon': No such file or directory

Then I check the gpg-agent manual. I found this:

   --scdaemon-program filename
          Use program filename as the Smartcard daemon.  The default is installation  
          dependent and can be shown  with  the gpgconf command.


and

   --disable-scdaemon
          Do not make use of the scdaemon tool.  This option has the effect of 
          disabling the ability to do smartcard operations.  Note, that enabling
          this option at runtime does not kill an already forked scdaemon.


Because I do not use any smart-card hardware I do not need any scdaemon.
$ systemctl --user --full edit gpg-agent.service

Adding --disable-scdaemon to ExecStart:
[Unit]
Description=GnuPG cryptographic agent and passphrase cache
Documentation=man:gpg-agent(1)
Requires=gpg-agent.socket

[Service]
ExecStart=/usr/bin/gpg-agent --supervised --disable-scdaemon
ExecReload=/usr/bin/gpgconf --reload gpg-agent

Reload the configuration:
$ systemctl --user reload gpg-agent.service

Restart the service:
$ systemctl --user restart gpg-agent.service

Eventually if restart is not responsive:
$ killall -9 gpg-agent

systemctl will restart the agent with the new option.

I have a similar problem with sending encrypted emails from Evolution. In the logs, I see the same error as yours. At the same time, Evolution shows an error that I don't have the target public key, but it does. Your instructions don't help.
